# send emails at times dependent on users timezone using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm relatively new to nodejs and was wondering what the best approach would be in setting up a automated job between set hours (lets say 8am-10pm every hour dependent on the customers timezone), to perform a task then based on results send users emails?

Answer (score 0):

The task you describe is not so simple at first:

1. You need to have some queue implementation, if you want something simple you can use Kue.js which uses Redis for storing the jobs. For more scaled solution would be using ZMQ or RabbitMQ.
2. The job processor, is the part where you have to interact with database and give you out the list of emails. Depending on the size of your email list, it's better if it could be splitted into chunks like 200 emails and then create "child-jobs"
3. Email sending, there are different providers and possible solutions. First your own SMTP server, Amazon SES, Mailchimp and other similar services. For the sending library there is already great, Nodemailer.

This is not the full concept, but should give you the idea. I am sorry if this is too abstract concept, but the question is not specific either.

Comment: That's actually given me a lot to think about, especially 1 & 2. I think I need to look more into these first.